# Why does ng-change always pass 'true' from model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switchery

When using the ng-change directive and passing model information to a function, ng-change always passess: true; regardles if the switch is on/off. I would like to receive both states of true and false depending on on/off state.

I am using a custom switch directive based on [switchery](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery) and [angular-ui-switch](https://github.com/xpepermint/angular-ui-switch)

```
<switch 
    ng-model="app.layout.isNavbarFixed"
    ng-change="uiSettingTypeChange('isNavbarFixed',
         {{app.layout.isNavbarFixed}})"
    class="green">
 </switch>
```

and

```
$scope.uiSettingTypeChange = function(name, setting) {
  console.log(name +' | ' + setting);
};
```

console.log always outputs:

```
isNavbarFixed | true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the ng-change attribute is already an angular expression so there is no need for the `{{}}`. What I guess is happening, is that angular sees the `{{}}` and thus evaluates it. So, at that point the ng-change effective looks like this:

```
ng-change="uiSettingTypeChange('isNavbarFixed',true)"
```

Then, when the change event is firing, it's just passing that true in every time. What you want should look more like this:

```
ng-change="uiSettingTypeChange('isNavbarFixed',app.layout.isNavbarFixed)"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly; genius. Thank you.